# Knockout binding on the anchor tag

Tags: knockout.js

I have an anchor tag with an icon inside it like this:

```
<a>
    <i class="icon-flip-2"></i>
    hello
</a>
```

I would like to replace the hello text with an binded element. Something like:

```
<a data-bind="text: myValue">
    <i class="icon-flip-2"></i>
    hello
</a>
```

The problem is that I lost the element < i class="icon-flip-2">

I want to keep it and be able to bind something on the anchor tag.

Thanks.

Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a virtual element

```
<a>
    <i class="icon-flip-2"></i>
    <!-- ko text: myValue --><!-- /ko -->
</a>
```

or a `<span>`

```
<a>
    <i class="icon-flip-2"></i>
    <span data-bind="text: myValue, if: myValue().length > 0"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: The virtual element seems to fit with what he needs. It gives him a way to bind text without using a new span.

Comment: @sngregory The span with an `if:` binding is what I would use, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: I agree with you, but it seems to go against what he's trying to accomplish since it would require a CSS change.

Answer (score 0):

Put your text inside a span inside the a tag and bind the span's text property instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to put your text in a span:

```
<a>
    <i class="icon-flip-2"></i>
    <span data-bind="text: myValue"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: @Golo: I prefer avoid using an extra span because I would have to adjust my css.

Comment: To be honest, if you're going to have one html element inside another, I prefer to then have everything inside an element.